# Determining if a semigroup or monoid can extend to a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I was thinking a few days ago, and it crossed my mind to wonder if one could extend, say, an arbitrary monoid to a group. My first thought was that it ought to be simple: Take a monoid $M$ with identity $e$, and for each $x \in M$, if there did not exist $y \in M$ such that $xy = yx = e$, define $x^{-1}$ to meet the condition; after carrying out this process, call the new object $G$. We should have an inverse element for each element of the monoid. But then I thought about it, and recalled that a group $G$ has certain properties that should be able to carry back to any sub-semigroup, e.g. properties of inverses. For example, if I have a group $G$, and there's some element $g$ such that $xg = x$ for some $x$, then $g$ is the unique identity. To see this, let $y$ be any other group element. Then we have
\begin{align*}
xg & = x \\
\Rightarrow (y x^{-1}) xg & = (y x^{-1}) x \\
= y g & = y ,
\end{align*}
so $g$ is an identity element for all elements of the group. But this would mean that if there were some element $x \in G$ for which there exists $e_{x} \in G$ for which $x e_{x} = x$, but there also existed $x' \in G$ for which $x' e_{x} \neq x'$, then $G$ would not be a group.

Let $X$ be some set, and define the semi-group $M = X^{2} \cup \{ \natural \}$, where $\natural \not \in X^{2}$ and $X$ contains more than one element. Define the semi-group by
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{a} \mathbf{b} & = \begin{cases}
(a_{1}, b_{2}) , & \mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b} \in X^{2}, a_{2} = b_{1}, \\
\natural , & \textrm{otherwise} .
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
Now let $M = S \cup \{ e \}$, where $e$ is just an affixed identity. Then $M$ is a monoid. Now assume for contradiction that $G$ is a group containing the sub-monoid $M$, and consider the element $\mathbf{a} = (a_{1}, a_{2}) \in M$. Then the element $e_{\mathbf{a}} = (a_{2}, a_{2}) \in M$ would satisfy $\mathbf{a} e_{\mathbf{a}} = \mathbf{a}$, so $e_{\mathbf{a}}$ is a right-identity for $\mathbf{a}$. If $G$ is a group, then for any element $\mathbf{b} \in G$, we'd have $\mathbf{b} e_{\mathbf{a}} = \mathbf{b}$. But if $\mathbf{b} \in X^{2} \subset M$, and $b_{2} \neq a_{2}$, then $\mathbf{b} e_{\mathbf{a}} = \natural \neq \mathbf{b}$. So $G$ is not a group, a contradiction.

This led me to wonder, when can you extend a monoid or semi-group to a group? Is there a known characterization? Are there some handy sufficient conditions? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a standard result that a *commutative* semigroup can be embedded in a group if and only if it has cancellation, i.e.:

$$ax = bx \implies a=b$$

For non-commutative semigroups and monoids, the situation is much more complicated.  The results are briefly summarized on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cancellative_semigroup#Embeddability_in_groups), but the gist is that infinitely many equations are required.