# Is it possible to localise the renormalisation group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, category-theory, mathematical-physics, localization

The renormalisation group allows you to consider what happens to a model when considered on different spatial scales. It is [not a group](https://www.quora.com/Is-Renormalization-Group-a-group-in-a-mathematical-sense), reflecting the fact that you can always move to a larger spatial scale, but recovering the smaller spatial scales may not be well-defined.

In category theory, [localisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localization_of_a_category) is a way to add inverse morphisms into a category, constraining some of its morphisms to be isomorphisms.

I was wondering **what happens if you try to localise a renormalisation group?**

Is this possible? Do you recover an actual group - and if so, how much information does it retain from the original renormalisation group?

Comment: you might be interested in this
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1550164/determining-if-a-semigroup-or-monoid-can-extend-to-a-group
and this
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cancellative_semigroup#Embeddability_in_groups
(I suppose your renormalisation group carries a monoid structure)

Comment: thank you, those links have helped clarify things for me